# how to make and iframe like themeforest.com Preview

Tags: javascript

how do i make an iframe like themeforest.com using javascript and iframe dom element.
here is the site reference. look at the top black line. and the whole website is loaded under it.

```
http://themeforest.net/item/focus-simple-one-page-template-2/full_screen_preview/236868
```

Comment: Excuse me, please. The code fixes height of *iframe*. Is your question about height of the iframe ('how do I make an iframe')?

Comment: look i am noob in javascript.. i am trying to learn.. can you help me to archive this goal? , reference is themeforest.com preview page..

Comment: But it is not clear what you want to do... please be specific about what you want. If you just say, *I want it to look like this*, we cannot help you, because we don't know what your website is about, what *it* is, etc. What specifically about the iframe do you want to know?

Comment: i have a web site have lot of third party products and those products have their own products webpages. i want when user click on product preview button. it should open a webpage.on the top their should be mylogo and menu (header div) and after header div their should be a iframe which automatically fix its height according to the webpage content. i dont want multiple scrollbars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to have an `iframe` that fills an entire webpage, you can just simply set the width and height of the `iframe` element to **100%** with `CSS`.

**Here is some example code demonstrating this idea:**

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
    Header
</div>
<iframe src="https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/iframe">
</iframe>
```

**CSS**

```
iframe {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0em;
    margin: 0em;
    border: 0em;
}

#header {
    background-color: #00AA00;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 2em;
    font-family: bold;
}
```

**A working example of this code is located at this JSFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/mq4Rf/7/.

Comment: hi this works but issue is still the same. their are multiple vertical scrollbars. i just want one with the iframe.

Comment: yessss i got it.. i open an body selector tag  body{overflow:hidden;} and it workss.......... thats alot :)